# How to use tikz to draw lines over multiple figures? How to declare tikzpicture over multiple tikzpictures?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This code gives me the following figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{test}
\author{test}%
\date{January 2022}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat{
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
    \draw [-stealth, thick] (0.75,0.9) -- (0.75,-1);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\\
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};   
\end{tikzpicture}}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:ablation}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like the arrow to be drawn over the other image instead of pushing it away like this

[image]

How can I declare tikzpicture over multiple tikzpictures?

Comment: look around page 260 of pgfmanual.pdf, `remember picture` and `overlay` key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way with overlay:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\title{test}
\author{test}%
\date{January 2022}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (image1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\\
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (image2) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\begin{scope}
    \draw [-stealth, ultra thick,] ($(image1.east)+(-1.25,0)$)--($(image2.east)+(-1.25,0)$);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:ablation}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Feel free to change the "shifts" to your preferred values

Output:

[image]

Comment: You will need a second compilation, Since overlay picture will find the real paths after the first compilation

Comment: thank you so very much. After spending so much time trying to understand the syntax I finally get it now!